# Help needed in formatting date in Java

Tags: java, date, date-format

Hi I have the following date as String format.

Input

```
2010-04-20 05:34:58.0
```

Output I want the string like

```
20, Apr 2010
```

Can someone tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");  
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM yyyy");

Date yourDate = inputFormat.parse("2010-04-20 05:34:58.0");
String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(yourDate);
```

Comment: one thing with this pattern (and mine, below): the month will be printed with a dot, depending on the locale. In french: "Apr."

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date date = inFormat.parse( "2010-04-20 05:34:58.0");

SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd, MMM yyyy");
System.out.println(outFormat.format( date));
```