# Date conversion in Java

Tags: java, string, date

How can I take a **string** in a format such as: `2008-06-02 00:00:00.0` and convert it to: `02-Jun-2008`?

Can I somehow take the original string, convert it to a Date object, then use a formatter to get the final output (rather than parsing the string myself)?  Thanks!

Comment: your query, 'can I somehow....' is correct.  Investigate that path further.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned JodaTime yet.  This must be a first.

Comment: @Paul: he mentioned in a comment he didn't want to use external libraries :) That was enough hint for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675666/help-needed-in-formatting-date-in-java

Comment: @BalusC, that's never stopped anybody before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert between a [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and a [`Date`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and vice versa based on a pattern. Click the API link, you'll see patterns being explained in detail. A 4-digit year can be represented with `yyyy`, a 3-character month abbreviation can be represented with `MMM` and so on.

First you need to *parse* the `String` of the first format into a `Date` object:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdf1.parse(inputString);
```

Then you need to *format* the `Date` into a `String` of the second format:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String outputString = sdf2.format(date);
```

Note that you need to take the `Locale` into account as well to get the month to be printed in English, else it will use the platform's default locale to translate the month.

Comment: For the outputString line, shouldn't it be `sdf2.format(date)`?

Comment: @justkt, that was already fixed during an early edit :) `Ctrl+C Ctrl+V` is evil.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 instances of `SimpleDateFormat` class. One for converting your input string to date and second to convert date back to string but in another format.

Here is an [example of using SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat startFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
DateFormat endFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String outputString = null;
try {
    Date date = startFormat.parse(inputString);
    outputString = endFormat.format(date);
 } catch(ParseException pe) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(inputString + " is not properly formated.", pe);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use SimpleDateFormat class like others have recommended.

Another suggestion if it applies in your case. If you are getting this data from a sql query you can also use to_char() method to format it in the query itself. For example: to_char(column_name,'DD-MON-YYYY')